# NHibernate event listener - is it safe to use HttpContext.CurrentUser in it?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using `NHibernate` event listener to produce event logs in database and I'm using `HttpContext.CurrentUser` to get current user id and write it to database field.

SessionFactory instance is singleton, event listeners according to documentation also, so I'm wondering if there is possible case, that event listener will call HttpContext.CurrentUser when current user has changed already, meaning that in events will be recorded user that has nothing to do with the change?

What if change was produced from different thread, is it possible that HttpContext at the moment of event processing will be not null and again wrong user will be written to events table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Httpcontext is thread safe so there is not a case where http context would change unexpectedly for that instance. It relies on the thread context to return the correct data for the specific user.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, but I check to make sure that the HttpContext.CurrentUser is not null.   If you define the eventlistener in another dll, the front end may be a web application or a local exe or for unit testing purposes.  In that case HttpContext.CurrentUser would be null.

```
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        return WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```